# Python, Flask, login with face recognition

Tags: python, flask, stream, face-recognition, yield

I got working face recognition system from Face_recognition toolbox. Now i want to implement this to login as second factor autentication using webcam.

If face from camera matches face from database n times, user is autenticated. How can i redirect from face autentication if function return generator yield?

This is function that return frames from webcam ( its while loop, i skip face recogniton process )

```
                start_time = time.time()
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                end = time.time()
                print(end-start_time,'---encoding image TIME')
                
                start_time = time.time()
                try:
                    yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 
                    bytearray(buffer) + b'\r\n')
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                cv2.waitKey(25)
                end = time.time()
                i+=1
                print(end-start_time,'---yield image TIME')
```

This is function that invoke previous function and display stream in html

```
@app.route('/clean_feed', methods = ['GET'])
def clean_feed():
    face_rec = Face_rec(0)
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    model = "large"
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT face_encodings FROM account WHERE username = % s',(session['username'],))
    account = cursor.fetchone()               
    if account:
        encodings = convert_encodings_to_intlist(account)
        username = [session['username']]
        r = Response(face_rec.facerec(capture, model, encodings, username), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')   
        
        while r:
            return r  
            
    return render_template('login.html')
```

After n times, if face is auteticated with face from database, stream stops, but i dont know how to proceed to next page. Generator is empty but while loop in clean_feed() still return Response. How to stop it and render next view?

Comment: IF you want to play with it for learning purpose fine, but just be aware that something like face recognition is a TERRIBLE single/sole factor for authentication, even more so over the internet where no physical presence is required.

Comment: Its for studies. I know face rec is easy to bypass but its second factor of authoriaztion. First factor are well-known login and password.